# php page cannot save data from the input fields on page realod

Tags: javascript, php

I am working on project that require the admin to change the entire website design from a setting page. i.e logo, color theme, copyright etc. I have set the setting page and is ok..However I don't have an idea on the best way to save the data so that any time the web page loads, it 
loads the data as set by the admin in the setting page. I am only looking for a rough idea..I will appreciate. thank you..

Comment: save the data in a database.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask here.

Comment: @rouline thank you for your answer.. For the logo, and the fields that require text inputs I know I can save theme in the DB. But what about the colors, dynamic form field inputs and drag and drop, can I also save the same data in the DB..I was thinking of using a static variable to store that data..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could save the values in a database for the dynamically allocated text, or save it as a JSON. Either way should work fine.

For the database:

- Create a table with 2 columns:

  - Key
  - Value
- Easily select all data by the corresponding key

**For example:**

*Key*: HEADER_TEXT
*Value*: Hello World!

You could do the same with a JSON file with the same structure:

```
{
    "HEADER_TEXT":"Hello World!", 
    "NAV_TITLE":"Navigation"
}
```

For the Theme, you could create a second table containing the hex/rgb colours etc. with the same structure as for your text.

Comment: That one answered my Question thank you so much...